# LG G2 sound randomly turns on from vibrate mode

Tags: audio, bugs, verizon, lg-g2

I have a Verizon LG G2 (VS980) updated to Android 4.4.2, which I always keep on vibrate mode.

However, every day, at *exactly* 3 PM, without fail, it turns itself from vibrate back to sound. It doesn't matter whether or not it's charging, if it's on wi-fi or data, or anything else.

Any idea what may be causing this, or how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Here is the solution which works perfect for me.

Settings>Sound>Quite Mode>Set quite time

after enabling quite timing, unselect all days and then disable quite timing.

[image: Set quite time image]